# table broken inside a block

Tags: tables, beamer, block

I am on beamer. The following code I put for creating a table inside a block.

```
\begin{block}{}
        \begin{tabular}{l|l}
            \multirow{2}{*}{$y = \begin{bmatrix}
                        w_{0}\\
                        w_{1}\\
                        \vdots \\
                        w_{D}\\
                    \end{bmatrix}^{T} *  \begin{bmatrix}
                                            x_{0}\\
                                            x_{1}\\
                                            \vdots \\
                                            x_{D}\\ 
                                            \end{bmatrix}  = W^T * X$} & $\hat{y} = W^T * X + \epsilon$ \\
                   & $\hat{y} = \sum_{j=0}^{D}w_{j}x_{j}+\epsilon$
        \end{tabular}

    \end{block}
\small where,
    \begin{itemize}
    \small\item value of $x_0$ is $1$. 
    \small\item $\epsilon$ is the residual error. 
    \small\item $W^T$ are the weight (coefficient of $x$) vector.
    \small\item $\hat{y}$ is the predicted value.
    \small\item \textcolor{red}{$D+1$} is the \textcolor{red}{dimension} of the vector $W$ and $x$.
    \end{itemize}
```

But I get following output,

[image]

Why the table has been broken? Is there any better method to do such thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\multirow` does not know, how large the table will be and it does not tell TeX back, the space used by it. In opposite, the user has to tell `\multirow`, how much regular rows it is allowed to occupy. However, the equation in `\multirow` is much higher than two regular rows. The matrix already uses four lines.

A workaround is to provide the needed space:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \multirow{2}{*}{%
      $y = \begin{bmatrix}
        w_{0}\\
        w_{1}\\
        \vdots \\
        w_{D}\\
      \end{bmatrix}^{T} *  \begin{bmatrix}
        x_{0}\\
        x_{1}\\
        \vdots \\
        x_{D}\\ 
      \end{bmatrix}  = W^T * X$}
    & $\hat{y} = W^T * X + \epsilon$ \\
    & $\hat{y} = \sum_{j=0}^{D}w_{j}x_{j}+\epsilon$\\[13mm]
  \end{tabular}
\end{block}
\small where,
  \begin{itemize}
    \item value of $x_0$ is $1$. 
    \item $\epsilon$ is the residual error. 
    \item $W^T$ are the weight (coefficient of $x$) vector.
    \item $\hat{y}$ is the predicted value.
    \item \textcolor{red}{$D+1$} is the \textcolor{red}{dimension}
      of the vector $W$ and $x$.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The next example uses some simple plain TeX box commands to set the two columns and align them at the top of the formula (not the base line of the first row).
Package `multirow` is not needed here:

```
\begin{block}{}
  \mbox{%
    \vtop{%
      \kern0pt
      \hbox{%
        $y = \begin{bmatrix}
          w_{0}\\
          w_{1}\\
          \vdots \\
          w_{D}\\
        \end{bmatrix}^{T} *  \begin{bmatrix}
          x_{0}\\
          x_{1}\\
          \vdots \\
          x_{D}\\ 
        \end{bmatrix}  = W^T * X$%
      }%
    }
    \kern\tabcolsep
    \vrule
    \kern\tabcolsep
    \vtop{%
      \kern0pt
      \hbox{$%
        \begin{gathered}
          \hat{y} = W^T * X + \epsilon \\
          \hat{y} = \sum_{j=0}^{D}w_{j}x_{j}+\epsilon
        \end{gathered}%
      $}%
    }%
  }
\end{block}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Your second method looks better.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses two side-by-side `minipage` environments inside the `block` environment. (The absence of a vertical rule is deliberate, as I don't think it's either needed or helpful.)

Note that I've also attempted to streamline some of the terminology.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\vskip-\baselineskip % per @samcarter's suggestion :-)
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\[
y = \begin{bmatrix}
      w_{0}\\
      w_{1}\\
      \vdots \\
      w_{D}\\
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
\begin{bmatrix}
      x_{0}\\
      x_{1}\\
      \vdots \\
      x_{D}\\ 
\end{bmatrix} + \epsilon = W^T X+\epsilon
\]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\hat{y} &= W^T X \\
        &= \sum_{j=0}^{D} w_{j}x_{j}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{block}

\bigskip
where
\begin{itemize}
      \item $X$ is the vector of observed or predicted factors. $x_0\equiv1$ 
      \item $W$ is the coefficient vector
      \item $\epsilon$ is the error term (a scalar)
      \item $\hat{y}$ is the fitted or predicted value
      \item \alert{$D+1$} is the \alert{dimension} of the vectors $W$ and $X$
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the new idea. But how to add a verticle line between two minibox? \vline?

Comment: @Maruf - Actually, I was (implicitly) suggesting that you get rid of the vertical line. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get that at the first time. Yes, your method of representation is also applicable in this type of situation.

Comment: @Mico May I suggest `\begin{block}{}
\vskip-\baselineskip
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}`? The additional spacing above minipages inside blocks is a known "feature" in beamer.

Comment: @samcarter - Great suggestion. Many thanks! (I didn't know until I received your comment about this 'known feature' aspect of beamer block/minipage combinations...)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Micos answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387171/36296), but using beamers own column mechanism:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
            \vskip-0.2cm
            \[
            y = \begin{bmatrix}
                  w_{0}\\
                  w_{1}\\
                  \vdots \\
                  w_{D}\\
            \end{bmatrix}^{T}
            \begin{bmatrix}
                  x_{0}\\
                  x_{1}\\
                  \vdots \\
                  x_{D}\\ 
            \end{bmatrix} + \epsilon = W^T X+\epsilon
            \]
        \end{column}
            \vrule
        \begin{column}{.35\textwidth}
            \begin{align*}
            \hat{y} &= W^T X \\
                    &= \sum_{j=0}^{D} w_{j}x_{j}
            \end{align*}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{block}
\bigskip
where
\begin{itemize}
      \item $X$ is the vector of observed or predicted factors. $x_0\equiv1$ 
      \item $W$ is the coefficient vector
      \item $\epsilon$ is the error term (a scalar)
      \item $\hat{y}$ is the fitted or predicted value
      \item \alert{$D+1$} is the \alert{dimension} of the vectors $W$ and $X$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Thanks for you suggestion! Looks much nicer now.

Answer (score 1):

without `\multirow` and right side of equation in `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}
      $y = \begin{bmatrix}
        w_{0}\\
        w_{1}\\
        \vdots \\
        w_{D}\\
      \end{bmatrix}^{T} \ast  \begin{bmatrix}
        x_{0}\\
        x_{1}\\
        \vdots \\
        x_{D}\\
      \end{bmatrix}  = W^T \ast X$
    & $\begin{aligned}\hat{y}   & = W^T \ast X + \epsilon \\
                                & = \sum_{j=0}^{D}w_{j}x_{j}+\epsilon
        \end{aligned}$
  \end{tabular}
\end{block}

\small
where,
  \begin{itemize}
    \item value of $x_0$ is $1$.
    \item $\epsilon$ is the residual error.
    \item $W^T$ are the weight (coefficient of $x$) vector.
    \item $\hat{y}$ is the predicted value.
    \item \textcolor{red}{$D+1$} is the \textcolor{red}{dimension}
      of the vector $W$ and $x$.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]